# Given an input to draw a rectangle canvas with selected background

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I want to make real time rendered rectange which is filled by texture of material you choose. I want to use HTML5 `<canvas>` and jQuery. In this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/1fhhtev7/ is how it should looks like. when you add "a" and "b" side it will generate proportional rectangle and when you click on material it will fill the canvas by texture of material.

Here is how the preview should looks like in final:
[image: final preview]

Can you help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

You should capture the values of the input elements and then set `width` and `height` properties accordingly.

`$('input[name=sideA],input[name=sideB]').on('input',yourFunction())`

Then you should make a function with a  loop where you draw the image.

```
var imgPosX = 0;
var imgPosY = 0;
var img = document.getElementById(YOURIMAGEID);

while(imgPosX < canvas.width){
    ctx.drawImage(img,imgPosX,imgPosY);
    if(imgPosX === canvas.width){
imgPosY += 50;
imgPosX += 0;
         }
if(imgPosY === canvas.height){
break;
}

    imgPosX +=50;
}
```

you call this function in your eventlistener.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
function draw(){
    $('img').click(function(){
    var $img = $(this).outerHTML;
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    var pat = ctx.createPattern(this, 'repeat');
    ctx.rect(40,40,width,height);
    ctx.fillStyle = pat;
    ctx.fill();
    });
}
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/UI_Designer/1fhhtev7/4/)

> Canvas draw  only to `change` number not `keyup` function